# How to upload file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-upload, firebase-realtime-database

I am a newbie in nodejs and firebase, but i need to upload files. I saw [this](https://mzmuse.com/blog/how-to-upload-to-firebase-storage-in-node) tutorial but could not grab much. I am totally confused. In this tutorial which is the function to pass the choosed file?
the code is:

```
const keyFilename = "./my-private-api-key-file.json"; //replace this with api key file
const projectId = "my-project-id-should-go-here" //replace with your project id
const bucketName = `${projectId}.appspot.com`;

const mime = require('mime');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
    projectId,
    keyFilename
});

const bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);

const filePath = `./package.json`;
const uploadTo = `subfolder/package.json`;
const fileMime = mime.lookup(filePath);

bucket.upload(filePath, {
    destination: uploadTo,
    public: true,
    metadata: {
        contentType: fileMime,
        cacheControl: "public, max-age=300"
    }
}, function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(createPublicFileURL(uploadTo));
});

function createPublicFileURL(storageName) {
    return `http://storage.googleapis.com/${bucketName}/${encodeURIComponent(storageName)}`;
}
```

I want to upload file when the users selects a file. Can anyone provide me something to start ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the tutorial you're following is for handling files AFTER they have been uploaded to your server. This is useful for services (like Heroku or OpenShift, as the tutorial mentions) with ephemeral file systems that won't hold uploaded content permanently.

You should try following [this tutorial](https://coligo.io/building-ajax-file-uploader-with-node/) instead, which explains how to build a front-end user-interface with AJAX. Once you've done that, then you might need to follow the tutorial linked in your question to get those files into permanent storage.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

use multiparty library it helped me a lot in my current nodejs project